# Which network monitoring package has the least odious SNMP interface?

Tags: monitoring, snmp

I need to monitor about a thousand devices, but the devices are mostly SNMP only devices. They aren't Linux or Windows servers or network gear(IT department takes care of that). I've been looking at a few of the popular monitoring/logging packages and they are all so... overkill and loading/configuring MIBs is like a 30 step process.  I think we want Alerts first and then might add on logging and graphs later.

The hardware is mostly Audio Video type hardware: Projectors, Video and Audio players, DSP...

Comment: If you're going to monitor anything using SNMP you need MIBs. The only way around that is to custom write your own code.

Comment: @John - I've some some NMS's that make loading MIBs a 2-click process, others where you have to convert the OIDs by hand, or manually import each one (Zabbix, I'm looking at you). I suspect they're trying to avoid a long import process.

Comment: @Mark, you may be right. I think the OP could do a lot to make the objective clearer, including telling us just what is to be monitored. Perhaps someone else here has already been through the exercise.

Comment: @Mark Henderson which one was two clicks?...

Comment: PRTG isn't too bad, but I wouldn't do more than a few dozen devices with it, which is why I didn't suggest it. Also, it's windows only and I found it quite irritating.

Answer (score 2):

Nagios has a commercial version called Nagios XI that will easily receive SNMP traps (and do SNMP gets as well). It may have TONS of other functionality but no one says you have to use it. If you are well versed in Linux you could also use the free (open source) version but if you are looking for something easy to administer, has a GUI web interface and can be up and running fairly quickly, I would recommend you take a look at it. It also has graphing ability if you want it to.

The web address is: http://nagios.com/products/nagiosxi

Comment: The non-commercial version handles SNMP just fine.

Comment: I agree, the OP was asking for something "easy" and I find XI to be a bit easier to use than the open source version.

Answer (score 1):

[Observium](http://www.observium.org/wiki/Main_Page) might be a good fit.  Sounds like simplicity is one of the design goals of the project.

Answer (score 1):

While its not two clicks, OpenNMS has a script to parse the mib, which you can include into your configuration.

They have an example, using the snmp information mibs:
http://www.opennms.org/wiki/SNMP_Informant_How-To

Answer (score 0):

SolarWinds Orion, I recall, makes this fairly easy.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest **snmpd** for linux clients and **zenoss** as a monitoring server, I used to work with it and they are awesome.

you can try my script to basicly config your clients too

```
#clone https://github.com/mrafieee/shell-scripts/blob/master/snmp-basic-config.sh
#chmod +x snmp-basic-config.sh
#sudo sh snmp-basic-config.sh 192.168.1.2 community-name
```

1. https://packages.debian.org/snmpd
2. http://www.zenoss.com